# Posting to WCF service from AngularJS Content-type issue

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, wcf

First off, sorry for the length of this but I wanted to include as much info as possible.  I'm writing my first typescript/angular app and attempting to call into our existing IIS WCFservices. The calls are cross domain.  Thanks for any input.

Service Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "LoginUser", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
LoginResponse LoginUser(LoginRequest request);
```

TypeScript Request:

```
class LoginRequest implements ILoginRequest {
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    ReturnListOfQueues: boolean;
}
```

Angular/Typescript Login Method:

```
loginUser(UserName: string,
    Password: string,
    DomainName: string,
    ReturnListOfQueues: boolean): ng.IPromise<ILoginResponse> {

        var base_url = 'http://[IP]/AuthenticationService.svc/rest/LoginUser';

        var request = new LoginRequest();
        request.UserName = UserName;
        request.Password = Password;
        request.ReturnListOfQueues = ReturnListOfQueues;

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: base_url,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            data: JSON.stringify({ request: request }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
        }


        return this.$http(req)
            .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<ILoginResponse>): ILoginResponse=> {
            return <ILoginResponse>response.data;
            });
}
```

When I call it as above with `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }`, the JSON shows up in Fiddler but the Content-Type is `text/plan' and I get a 400 Request Error

I can't post pictures yet so here is a link to fiddler screencap
https://goo.gl/photos/m75uzHi3E9KdkZhw5

If I edit/reissue the request in Fiddler and change the Content-Type to application/json, the service is called succesfully and I get the expected response data.

When i change the request to use application/json the data no longer shows up in Fiddler

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: base_url,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" },
    data: JSON.stringify({ request: request }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
}
```

Fiddler screencap2:
https://goo.gl/photos/VeJd9HSX46svA1HZ6

I also get CORS messages in Firefox when setting the Content-Type

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [removed]. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed). 

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [removed]. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

web.config entried for service

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

    <behavior name="restBehavior">
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"  automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />

    </behavior>
```

UPDATE:
I followed this post blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/

Now when I send the request in with `headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" }`, I no longer get the 405 error.  It sends the OPTIONS request which returns a 200 OK but the POST request is never made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the app in chrome and got the following `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed`

I removed this section from the web.config and it's working now.  Angular makes the follow-up POST following the pre-flight OPTIONS call

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `JSON.stringify` is producing some invalid JSON, and hence you are posting invalid JSON data?

If I try to Deserialize the Request body included in your first Picture I get the following error:

> Error parsing boolean value. Path 'request.ReturnListOfQueues', line 1, position 80.

I used the following code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"request\": {\"UserName\": \"admin\", \"Password\": \"admin\",\"ReturnListOfQueues\":false\"}}");
```

If I change it to:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"request\": {\"UserName\": \"admin\", \"Password\": \"admin\",\"ReturnListOfQueues\":\"false\"}}");
```

it works fine. (Added an extra double quotation mark, before false.)

Comment: Thanks but don't think that's it.  If I manually change the header in FIddler and reissue, it works without quotes around false

Comment: I know that it is valid to have no quotes, but the issue is that you have a single quote which is invalid. "ReturnListOfQueues":false"}, should be changed to "ReturnListOfQueues":"false"} or "ReturnListOfQueues":false}

Comment: Also, I can remove that value and just send UserName, Password and I get the same issue.  ReturnListOfQueues is not a required DataMember

Comment: my bad..I see what you're saying now..let me take another look

Comment: {"request":{"UserName":"admin","Password":"adminpw","ReturnListOfQueues":false}}  returns a 400 error sill